# Azure DevOps Server git clone returns 403

Tags: git, azure-devops

We have a local instance of Azure DevOps Server, I have issues trying to git clone from it using https, but it works fine with ssh (I need https because of git lfs).

I tried all the suggestions I could find, setting the proxy, using the credential manager, nothing works, and at the end I always get:

> fatal: unable to access 'https://myserver/org/project/_git/repo/': The requested URL returned error: 403

The credential manager actually never prompts for username and password, even if I deleted everything credential related from my gitconfig and Windows credentials (there was nothing here in any case).

If I try:

```
GIT_TRACE_CURL=true git clone https://myserver/org/project/_git/repo/
```

I get:

```
# logs
Info: Connected to proxy ...
# other logs
Send header: GET /org/project/_git/repo/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1
# other logs
Your system policy has denied access to the requested URL..
```

and naturally the 403.

Do you have any idea about what else I can try?

Comment: I was recently struggling with this too, and an interim solution I got to work was to actually add an entry in Credential Manager (Windows Credentials, Generic Credentials section):  I added git:https://myserver along with username and password.  After doing this it worked.  Ultimately however I'd like to be able to use a PAT token but I'm not sure how to do that with ADO Server...perhaps the format is similar to ADO but I've not had luck with it yet.

Comment: I believe the proxy error is related to your internal proxy policy setup.  I was having a similar issue even in the case of using a PAT - this was solved by removing `unset HTTPS_PROXY`.
As a bonus, to use PATs with Azure DevOps Server, you just need to set
`MY_PAT=<your_generated_PAT>`
`B64_PAT=$(printf "%s"":$MY_PAT" | base64)`
`git config --global http.https://<your_ado_domain.com>/<ProjectName>/.extraheader "Authorization: Basic ${B64_PAT}"`